# website resize differently on different platforms

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, masonry

I am making a website using Masonry and Magnific Popup. My goal is to make this web site responsive on different devices.

I have resized the browser on desktop to preview it, it resize very well on desktop. But the actual look in my phone is very different.

What it looks like in a resized browser:
[image: What it looks like in a resized browser]

What it looks like on iPhone:
[What it looks like in iphone http://media-cache-cd0.pinimg.com/736x/f3/86/9b/f3869b476e6fc31338965a2f6689aa02.jpg](http://media-cache-cd0.pinimg.com/736x/f3/86/9b/f3869b476e6fc31338965a2f6689aa02.jpg)

It looks like the whole layout got shift to the left in the phone.The similar problem also occurs in ipad/mini.
Any advises are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Its time to learn a responsive CSS framework, try Bootstrap or Foundation.

Comment: You need to post your code. And whilst Bootstrap and Foundation are great resources, there is nothing wrong with trying to use pure css to deal with responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the YouTube video is messing up the page width. Try adding some jQuery to make the youtube width responsive, for example:

```
  $('iframe').attr('width',$( window ).width());
  $('iframe').attr('height',$( window ).height());
```

But seriously, this won't solve everything down the line. You should learn Foundation or Bootstrap.

[image: Weird extra page width]